# If A calls B and B forwards to C, will C know the call was routed through B

Tags: asterisk, gsm

As the title states this is about GSM call forwarding.

When a mail is forwarded it's headers shows that it's forwarded. Is it the same when forwarding a gsm phone call?

More specifically if I set my phone to forward calls, in case I don't answer, to an asterisk server. Will I on that server have both the phone numbers? That is both the original caller and the one forwarding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your asterisk box using DSS1? DSS1 allows you to get the redirecting number (the GSM subscriber number in your case).